# How to load polymer?

Tags: javascript, html, polymer

I'm new to polymer and am trying to understand how to load it. I'm reading this

https://www.polymer-project.org/2.0/start/quick-tour

In their first simple example, they load a polyfill

```
<script src="https://polygit.org/components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-loader.js"></script>
```

which I understand the reason. But the next part, they load a html file, which appears to load the main polymer app.

They load it with a html import to here

```
https://polygit.org/components/polymer/polymer-element.html
```

Which this appears to load a bunch of html files which all have script tags in it.

Then finally to use polymer, you just make a class that extends `Polymer.Element`.

This seems really strange, to why they chose to import a ton of html files. Why did they not just stuff all that js into 1 javascript polymer library file, like jquery. Or is there a javascript file for polymer like that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't a Polymer js file.

As you noticed, Polymer is distributed as HTML files which are consumed with HTML Import links.

A single component would import `polymer/polymer-element.html` while an app which uses that element would import `polymer/polymer.html`. Both of them include all the JS code they require.

Why HTML and not JS files? Because HTML import spec prevents a given file to be loaded multiple times unlike the `<script>` tag.

Comment: ok that actually makes sense, because if it were loaded in 1 single js file, then if you imported 10 polymer elements, the single js file would be executed (downloaded once still) 10 times, but as html imports, it downloads and executes only once.

Answer (score 0):

you only need to import their script file and the declare the class which extends the Ploymer.Element.
and then use the custom tag.

Or you can use the CLI tool they provided to create a project directory

Comment: What is the link to their script file (I assume you mean javascript)?

Comment: @omega I recommend you download the js file via bower and import it locally. check the installation in the doc

Comment: I read this https://www.polymer-project.org/2.0/start/first-element/intro but I don't see any polymer js file

Comment: I saw that but even that says `<link rel="import" href="/bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">`. There is no  mention of a polymer js file.

Comment: @omega there is <script src="/bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-loader.js"></script>

Comment: Isn't that just the polyfil? If it is, I'm not talking about that, I'm referring to the main polymer js.

Comment: Basically 1 js file that loads the whole polymer element class.